# What format is this data stored as?

Tags: android, format

I'd like to parse the following information and would like to identify the format that it is in?

```
    {
  "interval": {
    "id": 0,
    "starts_at": 1317851120683,
    "ends_at": 1317851374436
  },
  "identifier": "2021902",
  "category": "music",
  "original_category": "",
  "buy_link": "http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/stat?id=6z5Z0DsswBo&offerid=162397&type=3&subid=0&tmpid=3664&RD_PARM1=http%253A%252F%252Fitunes.apple.com%252Fca%252Falbum%252Foh-my-what-a-fine-day%252Fid360945836%253Fi%253D360945883%2526uo%253D4%2526partnerId%253D30",
  "title": "Oh My, What A Fine Day",
  "artist": "Behind Sapphire",
  "album": "Behind Sapphire",
  "publisher": "Behind Sapphire",
  "itunes_song_id": "360945883",
  "album_art": {
    "src": "http://www.streamon.fm/player/getAlbumArt.php?u=http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Music/fc/73/1d/mzi.briyobdw.170x170-75.jpg",
    "width": 170,
    "height": 170,
    "alt": "Behind Sapphire",
    "link": ""
  },
  "next_song": "",
  "next_buy_link": "",
  "next_album_art": {
    "src": "",
    "width": 0,
    "height": 0,
    "alt": "",
    "link": ""
  },
  "banner": {
    "src": "",
    "width": 0,
    "height": 0,
    "alt": "",
    "link": ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON.
See this: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html

Comment: You can also use this website to navigate JSON strings, or to see them in a better formatted way: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Answer (score 0):

JSON, or JavaScript Object Notation, is a lightweight text-based open standard designed for human-readable data interchange. 
You can refer to wikipedia, and you could get some useful information

Answer (score 0):

JSON. In this web http://www.json.org/ you can found a extensive index of libs for parse this information.